# Caliburn.Micro multiple element custom Conventions (NumericUpDown.Value,NumericUpDown.Maximum)

Tags: caliburn.micro, mahapps.metro

I've been messing around with CM conventions trying to understand how they work but i haven't found a decent article somewhere explaining step-by-step how and why.

However I've found a few code snippets that i've been working with with some success. 
In this case, however, i don't understand what is going on.

I'm trying to bind a NumericUpDown Value and Maximum to a corresponding ViewModel property. I was able to do it with the following code:

Value

```
ConventionManager.AddElementConvention<NumericUpDown>(NumericUpDown.ValueProperty, "Value", "ValueChanged");
```

Maximum

```
            ConventionManager.AddElementConvention<NumericUpDown>(NumericUpDown.MaximumProperty, "Maximum", "MaximumChanged");
        var baseBindProperties = ViewModelBinder.BindProperties;
        ViewModelBinder.BindProperties =
            (frameWorkElements, viewModels) =>
            {
                foreach (var frameworkElement in frameWorkElements)
                {
                    var propertyName = frameworkElement.Name + "Max";
                    var property = viewModels.GetPropertyCaseInsensitive(propertyName);
                    if (property != null)
                    {
                        var convention = ConventionManager.GetElementConvention(typeof(NumericUpDown));

                        ConventionManager.SetBindingWithoutBindingOverwrite(
                            viewModels,
                            propertyName,
                            property,
                            frameworkElement,
                            convention,
                            convention.GetBindableProperty(frameworkElement));
                    }
                }
                return baseBindProperties(frameWorkElements, viewModels);
            };
```

However, an here comes the weird part, i can only make one of them to work. That makes me believe that i'm doing some noob mistake somewhere. It almost seems i can only call AddElementConvention and therefor only the last call is executed.

I would appreciate either a help with this piece of code or a reference to some good documentation that could help me with it.

Best Regards

Comment: Happened to me too: wanted opacity, enabled, etc. bound on a Grid. While debugging convention.GetBindableProperty(frameworkElement) showed only one property "Visibility".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i found out somewhere that CM only allows one convention per item so that's the reason of this behavior...

However since items like ComboBox allows binding for multiple properties (SelectedItem, ItemSource and so on...) i'm not completed convinced...